# How to Switch Focus to a Gnome Terminal Tab via Script or Shell Command

Tags: bash, ubuntu, gnome-terminal, xdotool, wmctrl

I am currently writing a script to open several tabs in gnome-terminal, and set their titles. I can open multiple tabs, but I need to change focus to those tabs (programatically) in order to set their titles from my script.

I use zsh and bash interchangeably, so any bash commands should work fine. I am starting to get familiar with `xdotool` and `wmctrl`, but unsure of a combo of commands to switch focus to an open tab.

What commands can I use to "switch to next open tab" or "switch to tab *N*" from a gnome-terminal CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with [xdotool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/xdotool.1.html)

On one line, first, open a new tab with the `key` command. The default behavior is to switch focus to this tab. Then, use the `type` command to run a function, script, or other program in the new tab. Last, use the `key` command to "press enter." Repeat for N-many tabs!

```sh
# inside a file loaded by .bashrc which contains all my functions:
function setupterm() {
  # run a command, like set a title, in the current window/tab
  customCommandOne
  # do the needful as described above
  xdotool key Control+Shift+t && xdotool type customCommandTwo && xdotool key Return
  # repeat for n-many tabs
  xdotool key Control+Shift+t && xdotool type customCommandThree && xdotool key Return
  # return focus to first tab
  xdotool key Control+Page_Down
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to send the signal from Bash Shell use `xdotool`:

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

In your script issue this command:

```
xdotool key Control+Page_Up
```

Comment: Thanks - this does not switch focus, however. Subsequent commands will all run in the original tab. My goal is to run commands in the new tabs that open.

Answer (score 2):

You could just set the title of the tabs when opening them:

```
gnome-terminal --geometry=80x25+0+0 --window --working-directory=<Firtst Tab Dir> \
               --title='<First Tab Title>' --command="bash" \
               --tab --working-directory=<Second Tab Dir> --title='<Second Tab Title>' \
               --command="bash" and so on...
```

I would have posted as a comment, but don't have enough reputation for that, yet

Comment: I think this is a perfectly viable alternative, and it solves my problem, even if it doesnt answer the question exactly. Id say it warrants its own answer and an upvote, thanks :)

Comment: Yep, I realized that, that's why I would have commented instead of answered...But now, thanks to your (and others) upvote I gained the right to do so. Yay! :-)